# Call stored procedure using ExecuteSqlCommand (expects parameters which was not supplied)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a stored procedure from EF using `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` since one of my parameters is a datatable.

Here are the procedure's parameters :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [mySchema].[myProc]
    @customerId INT,
    @indicatorTypeId INT,
    @indicators [mySchema].[IndicatorList] READONLY,
    @startDate DATETIME,
    @endDate DATETIME
```

and here is the c# code calling the stored procedure :

```
var indicatorsDt = new DataTable();

indicatorsDt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
indicatorsDt.Columns.Add("Ongoing", typeof(int));
indicatorsDt.Columns.Add("Success", typeof(int));
indicatorsDt.Columns.Add("Warning", typeof(int));
indicatorsDt.Columns.Add("Error", typeof(int));
indicatorsDt.Columns.Add("Other", typeof(int));

var customerIdParam = new SqlParameter("customerId", SqlDbType.Int);
customerIdParam.Value = customerId;

var typeIdParam = new SqlParameter("indicatorTypeId", SqlDbType.Int);
typeIdParam.Value = typeId;

var startDateParam = new SqlParameter("startDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
startDateParam.Value = startDate;

var endDateParam = new SqlParameter("endDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
endDateParam.Value = endDate;

foreach (var indicator in indicators)
{
    indicatorsDt.Rows.Add(indicator.Date, indicator.Ongoing, 
                          indicator.Success, indicator.Warning, 
                          indicator.Error, indicator.Other);
}

var tableParameter = new SqlParameter("indicators", SqlDbType.Structured);
tableParameter.Value = indicatorsDt;
tableParameter.TypeName = "MySchema.IndicatorList";

context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec MySchema.MyProc", customerIdParam, typeIdParam, tableParameter, startDateParam, endDateParam);
```

As you can see, all parameters are provided, none of them has a null value but I always get this `SqlException` :

> Procedure or function 'UpdateIndicators' expects parameter
>   '@customerId', which was not supplied.

I can't figure out what I am missing. Is the use of `SqlParameter` wrong ? Parameters are supplied in the same order in the `ExecuteSqlCommand` even if it is not important.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the parameters in the SQL string you are executing. Try creating your parameters with an "@" preceding the name and then changing the ExecuteSqlCommand call to:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec MySchema.MyProc @customerId, @indicatorTypeId, @indicators, @startDate, @endDate", customerIdParam, typeIdParam, tableParameter, startDateParam, endDateParam);
```

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
var bookIdParameter = new SqlParameter();
bookIdParameter.ParameterName = "@BookId";
bookIdParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
bookIdParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
var authors = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("usp_CreateBook @BookName, @ISBN, @BookId OUT",
    new SqlParameter("@BookName", "Book"),
    new SqlParameter("@ISBN", "ISBN"),
    bookIdParameter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I currently call my stored procedures with parameters.  Replace the parameter names/values with your own.  Keep in mind, you may have to list the parameters in the same order as declared in the stored procedure.

Create a SqlParameter array:

```
SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[] {
     new SqlParameter("@ParamName1", Value1),
     new SqlParameter("@ParamName2", Value2),
     new SqlParameter("@ParamName3", Value3),
     new SqlParameter("@ParamName4", Value4),
     new SqlParameter("@ParamName5", Value5)
};
```

Then call your stored procedure:

```
 _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(DbHelper.GenerateCommandText("SpName", parameters), parameters);
```

Here is the DbHelper code:

```
public class DbHelper
{
    public static string GenerateCommandText(string storedProcedure, SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        string CommandText = "EXEC {0} {1}";
        string[] ParameterNames = new string[parameters.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            ParameterNames[i] = parameters[i].ParameterName;
        }

        return string.Format(CommandText, storedProcedure, string.Join(",", ParameterNames));
    }
}
```

Comment: Slight improvement to allow passing parameters without first declaring a `SqlParameter` array: `public static string GenerateCommandText(string storedProcedure, params SqlParameter[] parameters)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
var customerIdParam = new SqlParameter("@customerId", SqlDbType.Int);
```

Comment: No, it's not working either, i get the same Exception.